# How one can know if the client has closed the connection

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, servlets, asynchronous

I've been playing with the new Servlet 3.0 async features with Tomcat 7.0.4. I found this [Chat Application](http://java.dzone.com/articles/servlet-30-async-api-or), that lets clients hang on GET request to get message updates. This is working just fine when it comes to receiving the messages.

The problem arises when the client is disconnected i.e. the user closes the browser. It seems that the server does not raise `IOException`, even though the client has disconnected. The message thread (see the source code from link above) is happily writing to all stored `AsyncContext`'s output streams.

Is this a Tomcat bug? or am I missing something here? If this is not a bug, then how I'm supposed to detect whether the client has closed the connection?

Answer (score 1):

The code there at line 44 - 47 is taking care of it,

```
} catch(IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
    queue.remove(ac);
}
```

And here too at 75 - 83, using timeout thingie,

```
req.addAsyncListener(new AsyncListener() {
    public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
        queue.remove(ac);
    }

    public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
        queue.remove(ac);
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** After getting a little more insight.

1. Tomcat 7.0.4 is still in beta. So, you can expect such behaviour
2. I tried hard but can't find the method `setAsyncTimeout()` in the doc, neither [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html), nor [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html). So, I think they dropped it completely in the final version due to some unknown valid reason
3. The example states, "*why should I use the framework instead of waiting for Servlet 3.0 Async API*". Which infers that its written before the final thingie

So, what I can say, after combining all these fact, that you are trying to work with the thing that is broken in a sense. That also, may be, the reason for different and weird results.

Comment: Well that would take care of it if the write operation would raise the IOException which is not happening. Thus you can close the browser and never get that exception. And the timeout is in this example 10 minutes. That's quite a lot if you have lets say hundreds of clients.

Comment: I tried the code with Glassfish v3 and it seems that I can get onError event with Firefox, but with IE it won't work. This is really weird.

Comment: @SS3: So, can we say you have no issues with Firefox?

Comment: It seems so but I have to do some more testing. I still don't get it why this would not work with IE. And with Tomcat 7.0.4 this does not work even with FF.

Comment: @SS3: Are you using `tab` to access the application and closing the tab? or you are closing IE Window and every instance of it? It might sound ridiculous but that used to make difference at least, previously.

Comment: I closed the whole browser not just the tab. This still doesn't explain why some browsers work with Glassfish but not with Tomcat. There has to be some implementation issues.

Comment: @SS3: Its just that somehow, browser is still living somewhere and consuming messages, otherwise you should have got exception. But the part where Tomcat is not working fine and GF is, is bit weird. Because GF actually uses modified Tomcat as servlet container.

Comment: Indeed, that makes it even more interesting.

Comment: @SS3: Try to shorten the timeout. BTW, I can't see that method here, http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html . Any idea.

Comment: The timeout is property of AsyncContext and not ServletResponse. The timeout is problematic since the container will terminate the asynchronous request if it doesn't complete within the given time limit. I'm not sure whether writing to AsyncContext's response will reset this timer.

Comment: @SS3: I mean try looking at line 072 of the original example first snippet. Its calling `req.setAsyncTimeout()` which is not there in the API docs.

Comment: Well yes, it seems that it has been moved to AsyncContext. I don't run the exactly same code but modified one. The basic functionality is the same.

Comment: @SS3: Frankly speaking, it doesn't hold here anymore. Close this question, ask a new one with exact code you implemented.

Comment: Ok, I'll post a new question with the exact code. But eventually I don't think it will make any difference. Thx for your replies.

Comment: @SS3: Perhaps we would be able to knock off the problem after looking at your code. We spent a good amount of time on this, we must try to reach some conclusion at least. What say you?